# How to hide and show bootstrap 4 cards by hovering over navigation menu through css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

Hi I'm trying to show and hide particular section of cards by just hovering over the menu list ,I can hide cards using css but can't display it by display:block property of css for specific class...

**HTML**

> Navigation  Menu

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">   
    <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link itemOne"  href="#">Product 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link itemTwo" href="#">Product 2</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

> Card Section

```
  <div class="card  item1" style="width:12rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top item" src="../image1" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body item1">
  <h5 class="card-title item1">Card title</h5>
  <p class="card-text  item1">This is a wider card with supporting text 
  below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little 
  bit longer.</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="card item2" style="width:12rem;">
<img class="../image2" alt="Card image cap">
<div class="card-body item2">
 <h5 class="card-title item2">Card title</h5>
 <p class="card-text item2">This is a wider card with supporting text below 
  as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit 
  longer. 
 </p>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.item1{
display:none;
 }
.item2{
 display:none;
 }
.itemOne:hover .item1{   //Not displaying item 1
 display:block;
 }
.itemTwo:hover .item2{    //Not displaying item 2
 display:block;
 }
```

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish this without using javascript?

Comment: @Jay Jordan yeah ,but if u have any solution by using javascript that would be a great help

Comment: See fiddle below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use jQuery to accomplish this.

CSS:

```
.item1, .item2 {
  display: none;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('.itemOne').hover(function() {
    $('.item1').toggle();
});

$('.itemTwo').hover(function() {
    $('.item2').toggle();
});
```

Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/5937/).

Comment: issue is still coming its not displaying the card but the css part is working

Comment: Is it working like you expect in the fiddle, or not there either? I was able to get the cards to display on hover in that example.

Comment: What version of bootstrap and jQuery are you using?

Comment: bootstrap -4 and jQuery 3.3.1

Comment: Is the example I linked working like you expect it to?

Comment: No its not working ....i think someway the class is conflicting with current bootstrap 4 classes

Comment: I mean is it working in the example I linked? In that example it shows and hides the cards when you hover over the nav element. Did you remove the CSS that I didn't include in my answer?

Comment: yes it is working in the example you linked ....No i didnt remove the css  in your answer but when i implement the same code in my project it is not working but in fiddle it is working.