# Hide/show cards in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, show-hide

Im trying to hide and show a few cards in bootstrap, but I can't figure it out. 
All cards have the class card (of course) and im trying to hide all those cards when a button is clicked. Here is what I have now:

```
function myFunction() {

  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".card").hide();
  });

  var game = document.getElementById("game").value;
  var resolution = document.getElementById("resolution").value;
  var graphic = document.getElementById("graphic").value;

  if (game == "Black" && graphic == "high" && resolution == "1080") {
    alert("Hello " + game + "! You will now be redirected to www.w3Schools.com");
  } else if (book == "Red") {

  } else if (book == "Green") {

  } else {

  }
}
```

The call for the function is correct cause the alert does work properly.

For some reason the

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".card").hide();
      });
```

part does work when outside the js function (when it's not connected to the button).

No idea if it helps but here is also a snipped of my bootstrap doc:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <!-- Results -->
        <div class="card" id="p2" style="width:200px; margin:30px">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://image" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Processor</h5>
            <p><a href="#">Newegg</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Newegg</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Newegg</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card" id="p3" style="width:200px; margin:30px">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://image" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Graphic card</h5>
            <p><a href="#">Newegg</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Newegg</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Newegg</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Here the things I've tried already:

The toggle [How to hide and show bootstrap 4 cards by hovering over navigation menu through css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49830079/how-to-hide-and-show-bootstrap-4-cards-by-hovering-over-navigation-menu-through)

Standard js document.getElementById(".card").style.display = "none";

I've looked at the react stuff, but I don't understand that.

Comment: Your issue isn't from your function, here's a working fiddle with the behavior you want. Since you didn't copy all your code, i had to comment the second part of your function : https://jsfiddle.net/m156gpvr/

Answer (score 1):

I think what you have to do is this if you want to make a show and hide toggle of all the elements that have the card class in your DOM.

```
var myFunction = function() {

 var divsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("card"); 
if(divsToHide.length>0){
        for(var i = 0; i < divsToHide.length; i++){

      if( divsToHide[i].style.display== "none"){
    divsToHide[i].style.display = "block";
      }else{

           divsToHide[i].style.display = "none"; // depending on what you're doing
      }    
}} }
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: This code did work for hiding the cards, but for some reason after running the by the button activated script the button also activates JQuery which resets the page. No idea why. I can't delete the JQuery CDN, because the gives problems with bootstrap.